# proper syntax for bpel bpel:doXslTransform

Tags: bpel

I am trying to do an XSL transform on an xml structure in a bpel assignment statement. There is a syntax problem, but I am having trouble finding official documentation. There are examples [all over the internet](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BPS300/Usage+of+XslTransform+Function) but I have not found a clear explanation. Here is my best shot. What do the last two parameters do? Why is eclipse saying the first argument must be a literal, even though test3.xsl is a string?

```
<bpel:assign validate="yes" name="Assign">
    <bpel:copy keepSrcElementName="no">
        <bpel:from>
            <![CDATA[bpel:doXslTransform("test3.xsl", $personalInfoServiceOutput.parameters), "middle", $positionSkillManagementInput]]>
        </bpel:from>
        <bpel:to variable="positionSkillManagementInput"></bpel:to>
    </bpel:copy>
</bpel:assign>
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature of doXSLTransform looks as follows:

`object bpel:doXslTransform(string, node-set, (string, object)*)`

The first parameter is the name of the XSLT script, the second parameter is an XPath identifying the source document (e.g. a variable, part, nodeset, node). The third and the fourth parameter is a key-value pair, the string is the key and the object is the value. Those pairs are mapped into the script's parameter context so that you can access these values by their name in the script. There can be any number of these pairs.

The best resource to look up such things is the [WS-BPEL 2.0 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/wsbpel-v2.0.html), doXSLTransform is described in Sect. 8.4

Comment: Why does eclipse not recognize the first parameter as a string?   <![CDATA[bpel:doXslTransform("urn:test3.xsl", $personalInfoServiceOutput.parameters)]]> //error: the first argument to doxsltransform must be a string

Comment: Did you try it with single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

When I use the following code :

```
<bpel:copy keepSrcElementName="no">
<bpel:from>
<![CDATA[bpel:doXslTransform("parseSample.xsl", $output.payload)]]>
</bpel:from>
<bpel:to variable="output"></bpel:to>
</bpel:copy>
```

I also get the error, that first argument must be literal string.

But, when I deploy my service (with error) to wso2 bps, it works fine.

You can try with this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Agree with NGoyal. Shows error in BPEL but works when deployed.