# insert string literal in BPEL

Tags: xslt, cdata, bpel

I am working on BPEL to compose some web services, the problem that I need to convert date type.

I am using:

```
 bpel:doXslTransform("SimpleTransform.xsl", $input.payload)
```

but the eclipse says :

> The first argument ("SimpleTransform.xsl") to function doXslTransform
>   in "bpel:doXslTransform("SimpleTransform.xsl", $input.payload)" must
>   be a literal (string).

any solutions?

Comment: This post may be relevant?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161204/proper-syntax-for-bpel-bpeldoxsltransform (specifically NGoyal's answer?)

Comment: yes, but no useful answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug on the plugin, just ignore it. It will work if you deploy it.